# How to manipulate pandas DataFrame to plot ggplot histogram

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a histogram given pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
weekday     ENTRIESn_hourly
0   0   604.620120
1   1   1084.888769
2   2   1307.073259
3   3   1335.901803
4   4   1305.176382
5   5   1333.800773
6   6   809.925317
```

It has 2 columns `df.weekday` and `df.ENTRIESn_hourly`

How to plot a ggplot histogram so the x-axis is weekday and y-axis is ENTRIESn_hourly ?

So far I came up with this:

```
plot = ggplot.ggplot(new_df, ggplot.aes(x='weekday')) +\
ggplot.geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +\
ggplot.ggtitle('NYC Subway ridership by day of week') +\
ggplot.xlab('Week day (0=Sunday)') +\
ggplot.ylab('Entries')
```

but the first line throws an error "pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It's using stat='identity' because the histogram is already calculated in the df.

```
plot = ggplot.ggplot(new_df, ggplot.aes(x='weekday', y='ENTRIESn_hourly')) +\
ggplot.geom_bar(stat='identity') +\
ggplot.ggtitle('NYC Subway ridership by day of week') +\
ggplot.xlab('Week day (0=Sunday)') +\
ggplot.ylab('Entries')
```

Comment: That works, thank you. How to change bar colors? I tried this: `ggplot.geom_bar(stat='identity', color='red')` but it makes bars to have red borders only.